# Calculating Fourier Transform in Parts - is it possible or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Say I have a signal I have sampled at N points, and I want to calculate the Discrete Fourier transform of these N points. Formally

$$y_{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}x_{j}\omega_{N}^{2\pi i jk } \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \forall\; k \in \{0,1,2,...,N\} $$

But let's say due to some restrictions, I can calculate the Fourier transform only on some m < N points, formally

$$y'_{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\sum_{j=0}^{M-1}x_{j}\omega_{M}^{2\pi i jk } \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \forall\; k \in \{0,1,2,...,M\} $$

Then, my question is would it be possible to calculate $y_{k}$ using $y'_{k}$

EDIT :

According to Stelios's comment below - operating on only first M samples is identical to loosing a part of the signal.

But lets say, you have stored the original $N$ samples in memory, and you can pick the $M$ samples from the N in any of the $N C_{M}$ ways possible.

(Could it be possible to recover the original fourier transform by exploiting the structure of the stored $N$ samples? )

Comment: You are effectively discarding the last $N-M$ samples of the signal. In general, similar to not being able to recover the original signal from only its first $M$ samples, you cannot recover $\{y_k\}$ from $\{y_k'\}$

Comment: Hmm, I understand. How about if you could pick the $M$ samples in any manner you want from the original $N$ samples (not necessarily in chronological order). This would of course assume that you have stored the original $N$ samples in memory first.

Comment: In general, discarding samples (in any manner) means loss of information. Only if your signal has certain structural properties you may get away with only using part of the samples. For example, if your original signal is "over-sampled", you could discard, say, every other sample and still not loose information.